# Background thread in XNA fails, "Collection has changed."

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

**I'm trying to create something like particle system on XNA 4, C#.**

I've created a function that makes particles move from each other if they get close enough. It contains cycle in cycle and therefore it is laggy. Without this function, program starts to lag with 400-500 of particles, and with function - nearly 180.

**Question 1. Can I improve perfomance by creating background thread to process these particle collisions?**

So, created thread with timer working inside. When I launch my game, it starts fine but when number of particles gets more than nearly 130-150, there appears a runtime error `Collection has changed`. Unable to perform enumeration." (it is a translation from another language, not the exact message).
Collection "neighbours" - local variable in a function `Particle.RunAwayFromNeighbours` - is being changed during the enumeration process, then, i think, one thread is somehow calling function while previous call is not completely performed. A strange thing.

I tried to use `Threading.Monitor` class to synchronize calls, but I have very few experience of multi-thread programming so I think i made something wrong. It didn't solve the problem, it's still the same error with the same count of particles.

I also tried to use `lock` operator but it's still the same situation.

**Question 2. How do I synchronize threads, finally?**

There is class Player, he "owns" some particles. Other thread works in this class. Code below is written using Monitor class.
Code ( ... is not necessary part):

```
class Player
    {
       ...
        Thread CollisionThread; 
        static double check_period=100;
        System.Timers.Timer checktimer = new System.Timers.Timer(check_period);
        public void StartCollisionChecking()
        {
            checktimer.AutoReset = true;
            checktimer.Elapsed += (o, e) => { CheckCollisions(); };
            CollisionThread = new Thread(this.CheckCollisionCycle);
            CollisionThread.Start();
        } //call in LoadContent
        void CheckCollisionCycle() 
        {
            checktimer.Start();
        }  //call 1 time in new thread
        void CheckCollisions()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Army.Count - 1; i+=2 )
            {
                var p = Army[i];
                p.RunAwayFromNeighbours();
            }
        }  //called in CheckCollisionCycle
}
class Particle : VO
    {
static float neighbour_search_radius = 2;
        static float run_speed_q = 0.1f;
        IEnumerable<Particle> CheckForNeighbours()
        {
            return owner.GetArmy().Where(a => Vector2.Distance(a.location.GetXY(), location.GetXY()) < neighbour_search_radius);
        }
        public void RunAwayFromNeighbours()
        {
            object x = new object() ;
            Monitor.Enter(x);
            try
            {
                var neighbours = CheckForNeighbours();
                foreach (Particle p in neighbours)
                {
                    Vector2 where_to_run = location.GetXY() - p.location.GetXY();
                    speed += where_to_run * run_speed_q;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(x);
            }


        }
```

Comment: FYI, there's no need to do `checktimer.Start()` on another thread. Timers already run on their own thread, so you can get rid of `CollisionThread`.

Comment: Also on which line do you have exception Collection has changed.

Comment: Timers work on their own thread? It's the day of surprises :)
Error appears on the line
foreach (Particle p in neighbours)

Comment: I got rid of thread. And nothing's changed. Can you advice something else?

Comment: Mind me when I ask, but... Why are you even using separate threads? Why not just do it in the main loop?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that `neighbours` is being modified during your `foreach`, try doing:

```
foreach (Particle p in neighbours.toList())
```

And see if that sorts it.

This will have you iterate over a copy of `neighbours`. It's not the *best* solution (you should avoid this collision in the first place) but it's a quick workaround to see if that's actually where the fault lies.

Comment: thank you for replying! I made this. Error still appears but the number of particles causing error moved to 180-200

Comment: Looks like you've got the same problem inside your `RunAwayFromNeighbours` method. Do the same thing there.

Comment: I have already edited the very method RunAwayFromNeighbours, this line: foreach (Particle p in neighbours.toList())

Comment: How about `CheckForNeighbours` ? If there's a foreach there you'll want to try the same thing.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this now... no, the same stuff happened

Comment: I still have no solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by making 2 things:
1. I added bool variable, that shows whether thread has finished its work or not, into class Particle. It looks like this:

```
public bool thread_completed = true;
        public void RunAwayFromNeighbours()
        {
            thread_completed = false;
            object x = new object() ;
            Monitor.Enter(x);
            try
            {
                var neighbours = CheckForNeighbours().ToList();
                foreach (Particle p in neighbours)
                {
                    Vector2 where_to_run = location.GetXY() - p.location.GetXY();
                    speed += where_to_run * run_speed_q;

                }
            }
            finally
            {

                Monitor.Exit(x);
                thread_completed = true;
            }
```

2. I changed line 
`return owner.GetArmy().Where(a => Vector2.Distance(a.location.GetXY(), location.GetXY()) < neighbour_search_radius).ToList();`
to line

```
return owner.GetArmy().ToList().Where(a => Vector2.Distance(a.location.GetXY(), location.GetXY()) < neighbour_search_radius);
```